# Copy SQL Server 2005 data to 2008 but not collation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I want to copy a SQL Server 2005 database to SQL Server 2008 but I don't want to pickup the collation from the 2005 db. I want to use the default collation in 2008.

Comment: Why do want to lose the SS 2005 collation? Was it incorrect?

Comment: The 2005 collation was incorrect.

Comment: I am trying the ApexSQL Script tool that will script all the db objects and then create them on the destination db.  It then creates insert statements for all the data.  The only problem is that the file is to big to execute in SSMS.  I get an out of memory exception.

Comment: I ended up using the OSQL command line utility to run the script and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the OSQL command line utility to run the script and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you backup/restore or detach/attach a database from one system to the other, you'll always have that database's collation come with it - there's no option to disable that.

So you can basically do one of two things:

- use one of those methods to move the database from SQL Server 2005 to 2008, and then change the collation after you've restored/attached the database

or:

- generate a ton of INSERT scripts from the old database and re-create its structure on 2008 with that server's default collation, and run those insert scripts on your new database

Answer (score 0):

Try DBSourceTools.
http://dbsourcetools.codeplex.com
It will script all database objects to disk, and then through a "Target Database", re-create the database, with all objects and data.
It has been tested on SQL 2000, 2005 and 2008.
It uses BulkCopy to insert data, so can import thousands of rows of data.